# Webform submission token for multivalue download field

Tags: 8, webforms, tokens

I'm trying to setup a webform that sends links which can be accessed to download a file.
It's working with the first file already, but I can't figure out how to create the token for the other files referenced in a multivalue field:

What's working (for one file):

`Here is your requested download: <a href="[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:entity:field_media_file:entity:url]" target="blank">[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:entity] </a>`

I have tried:

```
[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:entity:field_media_file:entity:url:0]
[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:entity:field_media_file:entity:url:und:0]
[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:0:entity:field_media_file:entity:url]
[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:und:0:entity:field_media_file:entity:url]
```

in almost every combination. It's not working.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Before diving deeper into this question I have another question: how do you know how many files are uploaded when defining these tokens? Is there always a set amount of files to be downloaded?

Comment: Right now the field is set to unlimited but it could easily reduced to a set amount if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not because you still don't now how many files are actually uploaded when adding the tokens. So if you manage to get it working with url:0, 1, 2, etc. and only 1 file is uploaded, you would have multiple dead links in the submission mail.

Comment: Why don't you make a "field" per file ?

Comment: `Right now the field is set to unlimited` @rémy better to have flexibility. A good solution for this case is to create a custom token that will print all the links.

Comment: What about using [hook_tokens](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.9.x) to interpret the tokens yourself?

Comment: @Beau, could you elaborate a bit more for non-coders in an answer? So at least the bounty is not lost... thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this issue is to interpret tokens on your own via [hook_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.9.x).

`hook_tokens()` is called every time a token is interpreted and gives you an opportunity to determine how that token is interpreted. Even though the token `[webform_submission:node:field_gated_download:entity:field_media_file:entity:url]` is already defined, it may be necessary to also implement [hook_token_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.9.x) or [hook_token_info_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info_alter/8.9.x) in order to define additional modifiers to the token.

It's possible that you might discover the exact token syntax that you need by inspecting the arguments passed into `hook_token_info_alter()`.

Here are two tutorials that cover using both `hook_token_info()` and `hook_tokens()` in order to perform custom token processing.

- https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-drupal-token-modules/
- https://medium.com/thefirstcode/tokens-replacement-patterns-in-drupal-8-d309132ba13d